# how to request a script more than once in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript

Can I ask how I can request a script more than once in wordpress. For example:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 2 ; $i++){
wp_enqueue_script('alerthello.js', 'example.com/example.js');
}
```

I expect the code to display two hello, but it display one only instead.

Comment: why would you ever need to do this?

Comment: Why don't you generate that 2 hello in your javascript by javascript for loop? Isn't that more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `wp_register/enqueue_script()`, you're basically pushing an element to an array named `global $wp_scripts`. Therefore you can't echo something twice as WordPress successfully prevents scripts being registered or added multiple times.

The reason is easy: Else, every plugin that registers or enqueues jQuery (or uses it as dependency) would add another instance. Which would be an undesirable result.

If you need to echo something twice, simply handle that inside your script file.